# Why when I add an input type submit in a form in HTML5, it does not submit, while I see no reason it shouldn't

Tags: python, forms, flask, server

When I tried to submit this HTML form, it didn't, then I tried it as a local file, and I got the same issue, can anyone help?
Note: I am very new to flask, so forgive me if a made a beginner mistake.

Here's my code (login.html):

```
<from action="#" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="userName" placeholder="Enter Your Name..."/>
    <input type="password" name="passw" placeholder="Enter Your Password..."/>
    <input type="submit"/>
</from>
```

Here is my relevant Flask server code:

```
@app.route("/login/", methods=["POST", "GET"])
def login():
    return render_template("login.html")

#not doing anything with the password at the moment.
@app.route("/<user>")
def user(user):
    return f"<h1>{user}</h1>"
```

Comment: Where do you expect it to submit to with `action="#"`?

Comment: The whole point of using that is to prevent submission.

Comment: [Form `action` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form#attr-action).

Comment: I handle the request on the same page, (I know it's insecure, but this is my first time making anything meaningful with flask), so I do not need to go to a different page, when submited, it post's the data to the server, (or at least I think so), and when I run .submit on is with JS, it says "Submit is not a function" if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

looks like you are using a wrong tag. Your form is not being submitted because you have used  tag. Try this

```html
<form action="#" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="userName" placeholder="Enter Your Name..."/>
  <input type="password" name="passw" placeholder="Enter Your Password..."/>
  <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

Also You can use submit button without form tag using java script.

Comment: It looks like you just copied OP's original code?  Did I miss something?  Did you mean to change something?

Comment: Thanks for the help, It would have taken me a long time to figure out that I misspelled form. Thanks!

Comment: @FrankYellin Please watch closely my friend. I have mentioned the mistake and then corrected it. He was using a wrong tag

Comment: D'oh.  I was so busy looking inside the form that I didn't see it was the form itself.  Sorry about that.

Comment: @FrankYellin I did the same thing. Then rewrote the code. Then i found the mistake.